# Cypher Query for searching through a list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I am working with `neo4j` and I have the below schema:

```
"person": 
{
    "name": "Robert Mathews",
    "nicknames": ["rob", "bert", "Mathew"]
}
```

I am searching for a few people who's name or nickname is `['mike', 'rob', 'nick']`
I am aware of how to search for a property through a list:

```
MATCH (p:Person) 
WHERE p.name IN ['mike', 'rob', 'nick'] 
OR p.nickname IN ['mike', 'rob', 'nick'] 
RETURN p
```

But now the problem lies the `p.name` and `p.nickname` is no longer a `string` type it's an `array` type.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to match input array with the person array and get the best match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APOC function [apoc.coll.intersection](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) can be helpful:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE
  SIZE(apoc.coll.intersection(p.name, ['mike', 'rob', 'nick'])) > 0 OR
  SIZE(apoc.coll.intersection(p.nickname, ['mike', 'rob', 'nick'])) > 0
RETURN p;
```

Comment: Hi sorry for the delayed response to the answer. Would you be able to tell me how would I be able to pull out a cosine value of the same? `apoc.algo.cosineSimilarity([vector1], [vector2])` for example if I want to do an intersection based on a cosine score above 0.90.

Comment: `apoc.algo.cosineSimilarity` only works on lists of numbers. There are some [text similarity](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_text_similarity_functions) APOC functions, but they work on 2 strings, not 2 lists of strings.

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this whereby you look for any item in the list of nicknames on the node that might exist in the list of nicknames you are checking against.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name IN ['mike', 'rob', 'nick'] 
OR ANY( nn IN p.nickname WHERE nn IN ['mike', 'rob', 'nick'])
RETURN p
```